# Sitecore PowerShell access allow/deny at same time

Tags: powershell-extensions, security, powershell

Hello Sitecore SPE Experts,
I have a very basic question, hope anyone help me:
I am using something like below

```
Add-ItemAcl -Path master:\content\home -AccessRight "item:read" -PropagationType Any - 
SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "extranet\Anonymous"
Add-ItemAcl -Path master:\content\home -AccessRight "item:read" -PropagationType Any - 
SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "extranet\Anonymous"
Get-ItemAcl -Path master:\content\home
```

at the same time read access allow and deny

[image]

anyone, please suggest me the how can I achieve to opt only one at a time as in Security editor it is showing me as allowed read access even after I multiple times run:

```
Add-ItemAcl -Path master:\content\home -AccessRight "item:read" -PropagationType Any - 
SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "extranet\Anonymous"
```

In Access Viewer it is showing as denied and in security editor shows allowed(image left section is Access Viewer and right is security editor):

[image]

Comment: You set Allow and Deny for the same user and the same item for the same access right?

Comment: yes correct, actually I created a small app using PowerShell on that I want to allow/deny access right like read/write but at the first iteration, I allow the access and in second iteration when I try to revoke the access then I found both rule present there